# Why can't Python dis module disassembly this .pyc file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode

I wrote a basic Python code in test.py

```
print("Hello World")
```

And then, I compiled with this code and generated .pyc file. I have now **.py** and **.pyc** file.

```
python -m compileall
```

Now, I use **dis** module for disassembly python bytecode but .pyc file not working while .py file working.

[image]

Why cannot a **pyc bytecode file** be dissamblied while **py file** can be dissamblied after compiled and bytecode is generated  (.py -->(compile) --> bytecode) ?

My pyc file:

```
B

hAı]   ã               @   s   e d ƒ dS )zHello WorldN)Úprint© r   r   ú"C:\Users\ismet\Desktop\deneme\a.pyÚ<module>   s
```

[image]

Thanks now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the `dis.dis` function supports both a source code string and a sequence of raw bytecode as input, the `dis` module as a main program, which is the way you're using it, supports only a file name of source code as input.

Since the structure of a `pyc` file starts with 4 bytes of marshalling version number, 4 bytes of modification timestamp, and a dump of the raw bytecode from the `marshal.dump` method, per Ned Batchelder's excellent [article](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html), you can use `marshal.load` to restore the raw bytecode from the the `pyc` file after seeking the file position of index 8. However, this header size was really meant for Python 2 when Ned wrote the article. As @OndrejK. points out in the comment by referencing [PEP-552](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0552/), you would have to perform a `f.seek(16)` instead since Python 3.7, and `f.seek(12)` between Python 3.0 and Python 3.6:

```
import dis
import marshal

with open('a.pyc', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(16)
    dis.dis(marshal.load(f))
```

Comment: I tried this code and it give an error "ValueError: Must have exactly one of create/read/write/append mode and at most one plus"

I used 'r+b' instead 'b' and response:

[link](https://i.hizliresim.com/VQbBav.png)

I guess, response is worng :/

Comment: You'd need to specify mode as `"rb"`, but while `dis` speaks of supporting raw bytecode sequence, output it yields when passed `bytes` of pre-compiled `pyc`, it does not look to be interpreting it correctly when I've tried that locally.

Comment: my response ([link](https://i.hizliresim.com/VQbBav.png)) is normally?

Comment: My bad. I've updated my answer with the knowledge gained from Ned Batchelder's article.

Comment: Actually this may also depend on version of python used... See [PEP-552](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0552/). So for instance in my case (py3.7), I'd need to `seek()` `4*4` -> `16` bytes to get past header and unmarshal the `code` object.

Comment: yes, its done. seek(16) worked but seek(8) not working. Thank you very much ♥

Comment: which type this code's output (b'\xe3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\.......................')

`with open('a.pyc', 'rb') as f:
   print(f.read())`

Comment: @Yunus What do you mean by which type?

Comment: bytes or different data type? So, if it is a bytes, can I do directly  "bytes to text" etc. process?

Comment: It is bytes indeed, but they are a sequence of bytecode meant to be executed by the interpreter and not readable directly. You can use the [`dis.Bytecode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.Bytecode) class to interpret it manually if you want.

Comment: endly, can this bytecode only execute virtual machine? Can I run?

 `1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Hello World')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 POP_TOP
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE`

Comment: You can run it too if you write your own interpreter to execute it, but that makes your code a virtual machine as well, so yes this bytecode has to be executed by a virtual machine.